# File manager respawns with ubuntuone

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, filemanager

Starting Feb 11, my Ubuntu 10.10 desktop respawns FileManager many times(hundreds).  You can observe the "Starting File Manager" processes at the bottom of the gnome desktop.

I can make this behaviour stop by:
System -> Preferences -> Ubuntu One -> Services -> uncheck "Files".

Can someone walk me though the debug process?

```
Linux 2.6.35-25-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 21 17:40:48 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I'm trying to reset the Ubuntu One configuration.  I found good information here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Bugs

**Look for "ROOT_MISMATCH in syncdaemon.log"**

After running through the steps to reset and restart UbuntuOne, no more "Starting File Mangager" respawns.

Comment: open a Terminal, and run `killall ubuntuone-syncdaemon; /usr/lib/ubuntuone-client/ubuntuone-syncdaemon --debug`, and pastebin the output.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards